# Pad NumPy Array based on Condition

Tags: python, numpy, where-clause, padding

Given is a `inp_arr` of shape `(m, n)` with `0`s and `255`s as values.
I want to **pad** the `0`s with **k** zeros in a [linear_ramp](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) mode.

- The `0`s are not necessarily next to each other, so there could be two groups of `0`s.
- The output dimension can be greater than `(m, n)`

I already tried this:
`np.where(inp_arr== 0, np.pad(inp_arr, 2, pad_with), inp_arr)`, giving me a `ValueError` that shapes cannot be broadcast together.
`pad_width` is taken from [here](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html).

**Example**

```
import numpy as np

inp_arr = np.array([[255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
 [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
 [255, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
 [255, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
 [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
 [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
 [255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 255, 255],
 [255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 255, 255],
 [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255]])

out_arr = np.array([[255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255],
 [255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255],
 [255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255],
 [255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255],
 [255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255]])
```

Thanks for your suggestions! :)

Answer (score 0):

That looks like an [erosion](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.grey_erosion.html#scipy.ndimage.grey_erosion):

```
>>> from scipy.ndimage import grey_erosion
>>> grey_erosion(inp_arr, size=(3,3))
array([[255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0, 255, 255, 255, 255],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0, 255, 255, 255, 255],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0, 255, 255, 255, 255],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0, 255, 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255,   0,   0,   0,   0, 255],
       [255, 255, 255,   0,   0,   0,   0, 255],
       [255, 255, 255,   0,   0,   0,   0, 255],
       [255, 255, 255,   0,   0,   0,   0, 255]])
```